# Restricting to enter same key data again in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am testing my fabric chaincode, where I am creating one car record. Now I am able to create different record with same key, and also even after deleting the key record , I am able to create entry with same key. I want to prevent it, so I must query whole ledger data whether the key existed before or not, but its very resource and time consuming once data grows. Is there any other efficient way to do it, rather than querying all the blocks ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible without iterating all blocks if you delete key.

How about adding one more variable that indicates whether the key is valid or not on your struct instead of using DelState?
ex)

```
type someStruct struct {
    SomeMemeberVariable1 someType `json:"someMemberVar1"`
    ...
    Deleted bool `json:"deleted"`
}
```

and check this variable later

```
buffer, _ := APIstub.GetState(~~)

if len(buffer) == 0 {
  return shim.Error("Not existing key")
}

something := someStruct{}
json.Unmarshal(buffer, &something)

if something.Deleted {
  return shim.Error("Already delted key")
}
```

Comment: Ok then it means while deleting the record I just need to make the fields null rather than using delstate API.

Comment: @user9040429 Oh, yes. You are right. You can just make the fields null instead of using DelState.

Comment: But then again there will be extra records int the current state. I was thinking whether there can be a store where we can maintain the keys, and can cross check there for the existence of key of new record to be entered.

Answer (score 0):

This restriction probably should be a part of the chaincode program, without querying the ledger every time. Maintain a list of currently entered keys and before putting incoming keys in ledger, check the list to make sure the key is new. Maybe use a golang hashmap data structure to implement this list.